# How do you rollback a Migration Bundle in Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-migrations

I'm fairly new to Azure Devops and have learned how to apply a migration bundle in a pipeline. This is working, however I would like to know how to rollback a migration bundle in this pipeline, in case something has gone wrong? Is this a good idea/good practice?

I guess I could query the _efmigrationshistory table and grab the latest record and re-apply it if anything goes wrong with the migration bundle step - this should work?

Can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the '[**`dotnet ef migrations script`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script)' command to generate the [SQL scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts) for rollback by using a **`{from migration}`** that is newer than the **`{to migration}`**.

```
dotnet ef migrations script {from migration} {to migration}
```

[image]

You also can try to call '[**`dotnet ef migrations remove`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-remove)' command to remove the last migration and roll back the code changes that were done for the latest migration.

[image]

After fixing the wrong things from the rolled back code, you can try to use the '[**`dotnet ef migrations bundle`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-bundle)' to generates a new migration bundle.

For more details, you can reference the following documentations:

- [**Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)
- [**Managing Migrations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
- [**Applying Migrations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

---

In Azure Pipelines, you can use a task such as [**`DotNetCoreCLI@2`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines), [**`Bash@3`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines), [**`CmdLine@2`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines) or [**`PowerShell@2`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run the related '**`dotnet ef`**' commands.

---

Comment: @Dan, Have you tried the methods shared in my above answer for rollback the EF migration? Do the methods work for you? Do you have any update on this?

Comment: I'm so sorry for not replying sooner, I was busy at work and had forgotten I posted this. Ok, so, because I want to sort this in the pipeline, the solution posted doesn't quite work since I want it to be dynamic and automated. I guess I could query the database possibly for the last two database migrations and create the script from that?

Comment: Btw, for anybody wanting to know the visual studio package manager console equivalent code for the backup script, it would be - Script-Migration -From LatestChange -To PreviousChange